# Are these things still in use in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I am undergoing training in asp.net and the topics which are being taught there these days are repeater and datalist control. I want to know that whether these things are used frequently in the companies. The other thing i want to know is that what are the topics which i should learn  in depth so as to get a job. I don't want to go through out dated topics.

I am not aware of what's most demanding in asp.net job sector. Please guide me through.

Comment: Asp.net is still all over the place, but MVC is the future.

Comment: More suitable question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ASP.Net won't dissepear so easily, even when MVC is much much better and the simple reason is there are too many applications (legacy code) using ASP.Net. Now even when MVC is the future, you should know ASP.Net, at least the basics, and if you want to get a Microsoft certification you DO NEED to learn ASP.Net, in the exam MVC is just about 20% or less of the total score. Just think about this, MVC is built **on top of ASP.Net** so you need to understand at least the basics

Comment: I agree with dbaseman. Now that the web gets more and more interactive, having client-side skills and doing less work on the server is the way to go, and MVC is just much better suied for that.

Comment: @Jupaol, ASP.NET MVC uses the same processing pipeline, but the whole page rendering and lifecycle is replaced, so that (while techically correct) writing that MVC is built on top of ASP.NET is somewhat misleading. To do pure MVC you need to forget pretty much everything taught about using the traditional ASP.NET Webforms - all this specific postback handling, sessionstate, pagestate etc. is gone, and *unlearning* that seems to be the hard part for seasoned ASP.NET Webforms developers when they are switching to MVC (I had some employees of mine that were struggeling a bit in the transition).

Comment: @Lucero I agree with you, they are different (if they wouldn't what would be the point to create MVC). But still many of the base concepts of ASP.Net still apply and will apply because MVC is just a small framework built on top of ASP.Net. But I agree they are different, the transition is complicated because you need to learn the new concepts (of the MVC framework). But at the end, MVC is just another framework, knowing the theory behind is always your best bet and that will give you a huge advantage against other developeres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, they are still in use. However, if you are new to Asp.net you might put more effor into learning ASP.NET MVC instead of Webforms.

MVC is a more modern approach with clean separation of concerns. Also you do not get the viewstate / abstraction that webforms has. Find out more here: http://www.asp.net/mvc

However, a lot of sites are still using the webforms approach and they are doing fine. Invest your time in the controls, in Linq and entity framework,

Answer (score 0):

Data GridView, User Data Validation, and  learn  some  basics as like Binding data, xml parser etc.

Answer (score 0):

yes 
talking about Asp.net all the server controls are used and will be used.. 
however Asp.net in itself isnt very good for learning website making as it abstracts away the underlying beautiful http request/response architecture of the web.
so if you are learning asp.net lay a great stress on ViewState that would also help you ultimately build the basics. 
With it caching and update panel for ajax are also important. if possible use jquerys ajax that would tell you a lot about the AJAX thing and also would save your time.(i remember just bumping my head on update panel for hours trying to figure out what is going wrong).

then there are features in the c# language itself like linq which are very helpful with connecting to any sort of database on which you should lay stress

Answer (score 0):

Every control group in asp framework is important.It depends upon the requirement of your application.To become good developer

1.)Clear all basics related with framework.

2.)You must know about all controls.

3.)You must know how you play with data.